# Android DrawerLayout and NavigationView not fully expanded

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, navigationview

Hi I have build a DrawerLayout with a NavigationView and a Toolbar. The problem is that the NavigationView does not fully expand like in the picture. I tried to use android:fitsSystemWindows = true and false but none worked.
[image]

This is my code in the layout file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_sceneform_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/sceneform_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_menu_nav_host"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        />

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_menu_nav_host"
             android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:defaultNavHost="true"
                        app:navGraph="@navigation/menu_navigation" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:menu="@menu/hamburger_menu"/>
            </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I want to remove the gray areas where the status bar normally is and the grey area in the bottom designated for the action buttons on the mobile device. Is that possible or do I have to do a custom design?

Comment: Could you post the entire xml file?

Comment: It is now added.

Answer (score 0):

Put new style in your style.xml folder like this;

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and define it in your manifest file like;

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```